# Setting a the background image of a div from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to make a div and set the background image from an array of images, and make a two buttons that will change the picture to the next image in the array, or the previous image of the array. I've been looking around stackoverflow and w3 schools, but I don't know why it's not working.

```
var backgroundImage = new Array();
backgroundImage[0] = "np.jpg";
backgroundImage[1] = "putin.png";
backgroundImage[2] = "fob.jpg";

function nextImage()
var img = document.getElementById(element);
for(var i = 0; i < backgroundImage.length;i++)
    for(var i = 0; i < backgroundImage.length;i++) {
        document.getElementById(element).src = [0].src;
        document.style.backgroundImage="url(backgroundImage[0])";
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do with `document.getElementById(element).src = [0].src;` and you should use different iteration variables in the nested loops for instance `i` and `j` instead of just `i`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I have no idea what I'm doing in this class. I'm only taking it because it was the only thing open. I've never programmed before, this a lot of this is new to me. I've just been finding code from stackoverflow for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not evaluating the array, you are creating a literal you want

```
 document.style.backgroundImage="url(" + backgroundImage[0] + ")";
```

Comment: For the full feature you will want to change the `0` in `[0]` to the appropriate value.